# Excel VBA, over flow error

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA in my excel sheet and it gives me an overlfow error. When I checked I found out that it was related to data error which shows unilmited "#" character in one cell.

All values in each cell is assigned to a string variable and when this cell comes in generates an overflow error. I tried to validate this using an if condition, but whenever we check cell.value this generates an overflow error. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not get a runtime error if you just read the cell text:

```
s = Range("C2").Text
Debug.Print s
' returns: "###########"
```

If you really want to read the cell value, and not the cell text (why you would need this, I have no idea, since you're stuffing it in a String anyway) then this is a workaround, assuming the #### are caused by dates Jan 1, 10,000 AD or later.

```
Const MaxDateSerial As Double = 2958466
Dim s As String
Dim dbl As Double
Dim nf As Variant

' Save original number format
nf = Range("C2").NumberFormat

' Use read-safe number format to read cell content
Range("C2").NumberFormat = "General"
dbl = Range("C2").Value

' Restore original number format
Range("C2").NumberFormat = nf

If dbl < MaxDateSerial Then
    s = Range("C2").Value
Else
    s = "Date overflow!"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing something like

```
Dim s as string
Dim cl as Range
...
s = cl
' or
s = cl.value
```

`s` will be set to the value as diplayed on the sheet, *which includes an error*
(in the form "`Error <Error Code>`" if that's what the sheet displays

If the underlying cell *value* is valid, you should be able to access if using `cl.value2`

If you are doing somthing like

```
Dim v as Variant
Dim s as string
Dim r as Range
...
Set r = <SomeRange>
v = r
...
```

And one or more cells in range `r` are an error, then `Runtime Error 6 Overflow` will occur

To advise further, please post details of the code, where the error occurs, cell value and cell formatting

The ############### display for dates occurs if the date serial is before 1/1/1900 (negative) or after 1/1/9999 (> 2958101) **EDIT** actually 31/12/9999 = 2958465

Comment: +1 for a good answer to an ungrateful bloke's unclear question. BTW overflow occurs at 31/12/9999, on Excel 2003 at least.

Comment: Thank @Jean - your are right about the date - a typo on my part

Answer (score -1):

Try using the "ISERROR()" function to filter out the invalid values.

```
IF(ISERROR(A1),0,A1)
```

Comment: Whenever we use any validation for example if (isError(objCell.Value)), this gives an runtime error

Comment: The `ISERROR` worksheet function doesn't work for #####. Neither does the `IsError` VBA function.