# getting overflow error, when I used the function "ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count" to find the count in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting an overflow error, when I tried to use the function

`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`

in VBA Excel

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel VBA, over flow error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327069/excel-vba-over-flow-error)

Comment: Even though the question is probably already answered, you should put a little more details so we don't have to guess...

Comment: Had the same error because I assumed Integer was 32-bit (+/- 2.14B). [But in Interop COM it goes down to 16-bit (+/- 32K).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/integer-data-type#programming-tips)

Answer (score 9):

I am going on assumption you have something like the following:

```
Dim x as Integer

x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

To fix simply change it to:

```
Dim x as Long

x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Or

```
Dim x&

x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

The ampersand (&) type-declaration character represents a Long

The Integer and Long data types can both hold positive or negative values. The difference between them is their size: Integer variables can hold values between -32,768 and 32,767, while Long variables can range from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

Because Excel worksheets can have more then 32,767 rows, you cannot ***ALWAYS*** fit the number of rows into an integer, and must use a Long.

Comment: or on a 64bit machine you may use [`Dim x as LongLong` or `Dim x^`](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/hello-world/vba-syntax/)

Comment: @mehow But for now excel sheets only can contain up to 1048576 Rows. Although correct you may want to use LongLong if you are on a 64Bit machine and referencing by used cells as that can be up to 17,179,869,184, and would overflow a Long, although from a performance standpoint you should avoid working with that many cells at once, and if you have that much data Excel is most likely not the best way to work with the data.

Comment: +1 thanks for saying this I've already said that thousands of times on so ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined your variable as an integer rather than a long or float?  If there are more than 32256 or something rows it's too big to be an integer.

Comment: [did you mean 32767?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164754(v=office.10).aspx)